# Expand a definite list into variables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, destructuring

Check this below code [this works fine]

```
val a = "1,2,3"

val split = a.split(",")
val x = split.get(0)
val y = split.get(1)
val z = split.get(2)

println(x) // 1
println(y) // 2
println(z) // 3
```

In Kotlin, is there a better way to get the value of a definite array into these variables, like

```
val a = "1,2,3"
val (i, j, k) = a.split(",") // ...{some magic code to put each item against variables i,j,k}

// This is how i want to use it
println(i) // 1
println(j) // 2
println(k) // 3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you actually try to run your code? It works just fine:

```
val a = "1,2,3"
val (i, j, k) = a.split(",")

println(i)
println(j)
println(k)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

The reason it works is because of Kotlin's [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html). For lists, you can do this for up to 5 items because it has [5 component functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/#extension-functions) defined.

Comment: You can also define `component6()` and so on, as an extension to List<T> to destruct more than 5 as well :^)

Comment: I ran this in Scratch file only and it said 
`Unresolved reference: i`
`Unresolved reference: j`
`Unresolved reference: k`

Hence I assumed this doesn't work.

I enabled `use REPL` and it did worked in Kotlin Scratch file. Also worked in a simple kotlin main fun. Thanks !